# Book about a Kid/Teenager with the ability to shrink to cellular level

Tags: story-identification

I've been looking for this book for a while now, and can't remember the name. Google hasn't helped much, as most Google searches lead me to Ant-Man comics.

Here is what I remember from the book: we follow a male kid/teenager (I do not remember his age), who finds he has the ability to shrink to cellular level, and go into other people's bodies (and maybe his own as well? I am not positive about that).

Much like the Osmosis Jone movie, or the Cells at work anime, in the book, the cells of our body have their own personalities and society.

Here is some standout things I remember:

- One the protagonist's friends had a disease similar to brittle bones, it is also implied/shown that he has the same kind of abilities as the protagonist.
- The protagonist's abilities are inherited from his father
- At some point, while in his own/someone else's body, the protagonist needs to use a submarine to cross some kind of river
- When inside his own/someone else's body, the protagonist strikes up a friendship with two cells, one female, one male.
- The protagonist's ability also translated to people/item he was in contact with, if I remember correctly, towards the end of the book, he has to go back to normal size in an emergency situation, which leads to the two cells he befriended being brought into the normal world with him.
- The story ended in a cliffhanger, strongly implying there was a second tome.

Another part I think I remember from this book, as that there was some shadowy organisation looking for some MacGuffin that had been hidden by the protagonist's father, and the way to find it was hidden somewhere in the protagonist's body.

This is a story I have read between 10-15 years ago (2002-2007), but it could have been second-hand.

Comment: I got excited when I saw references to the eponymous character of *Christopher* by RIchard Koff was noted to have the power to shrink down and enter bodies, and he learns at the end that his father has the same training, but nothing else matches, and it's more about The Headmaster unlocking Christopher's psychic abilities.

Comment: [Lenny Cyrus, School Virus](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15814478-lenny-cyrus-school-virus)? It isn't close enough for me to venture an answer, for example Lenny's friend Harlan doesn't have brittle bones, but it's the closest I can find.

Comment: @JohnRennie sadly no, the synopsis is close, but it doesn't match, at the very least it looks like an interesting read, so that's a plus.

Comment: "cross some kind of river" in the body or in the real life level?

Comment: @DialFrost this was inside of his body

Comment: Did the 2 cells go to human size ish?

Comment: @DialFrost towards the end of the book yes (if my memory is correct that is)